# IVR Application using Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ivr

Is it possible to create an IVR application using Drupal?

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you are trying to do and add some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing to "Interactive Voice Response" then I suggest on looking into [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) as the basis to your IVR.
Take a look into this [discussion](http://drupal.org/node/914748) for more information regarding to integration between Drupal and Asterisk (or other IVR system.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a SDK and a sample IVR system.

This sample IVR system can be the basis of an IVR system which works with Drupal. You can config this sample IVR system via HTTP. With the help of this I hope you can create the IVR system which uses Drupal.

You can read more about it here:
http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_117-how-to-use-the-c-sip-softphone-source-implementation-of-ozeki-voip-sdk-for-dtmf-ivr-voip.html